# Loop for a specific category for homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

For my homepage I want to display posts for a specific category (for example category "food") instead of the default display of all posts.

How can this be accomplished? Is it true that I am supposed to use `wp_query()` and avoid `query_posts()`?
Also, will I need to reset with `wp_reset_postdata();` for this loop in `index.php` ?

I have read codex and googled around, but still am not confident with altering the Loop.

I thought the code below would work but I get White Screen of death in WordPress Themes 2012 and 2013. I replaced the code in `index.php` with

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=1');
if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

**Edit:**

White Screen of Death was due to a missing `?>` elsewhere in my `index.php` file. Noob mistake. But now I am having issues with pagination. Page 2 displays the same posts as page 1. What could be wrong?

My code for pagination inside `functions.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
    function my_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer   
        echo paginate_links( array(
             'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ), 
             'format' => '?paged=%#%',
             'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), 
             'prev_next'    => True,
             'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ) );
}
```

.
.
**Edit:**

I used Pieter Goosen's solution below. Problems fixed.

Comment: This block of code isn't broken, so there's likely a mistake somewhere else on the page. Have you checked your error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change the main query for a custom query on the home page or any archive page. Custom queries is meant for secondary content, not to display your main content. I have done a very detailed post on this matter on WPSE which you can check out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545). It also covers a bit why you should **never use** `query_posts`.

To solve your problem, delete your custom query from your index.php, and just add the default loop back like

```
if(have_posts()){
   while(have_posts()) {
     the_post();

     //YOUR LOOP ELEMENTS

   }
}
```

You will now again see all posts on your home page. To only show the selected category on your homepage, use `pre_get_post` to alter the main query before it is executed. Add this to your functions.php

```
function show_only_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_only_category' );
```

This will sort out your pagination problem as well

**EDIT**

For the sake of SO users, I have reposted my answer from WPSE to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/1908141) by same OP

Comment: Thanks so much Pieter! This works perfectly and pagination is working! I'm a bit confused on terminology. Does a "custom query" always look like this: ----- $query = new WP_Query('cat=1'); ----- ? I'm confused cause I don't see this exact code in the [Codex for custom query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) ----- Also, is query_posts() also referred to as a custom query?

Comment: I'm confused about terminology also because of this [article about reseting loops](http://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/) ----- wp_reset_postdata() -> best used after custom or multiple loops created with WP_Query ----- wp_reset_query() -> best used after a query_posts loop to reset a custom query ----- He referred to query_posts as a custom query

Comment: The following are used and regarded as custom queries, `WP_Query`, `get_posts` and `query_posts`. The codex page about the loop is badly written. `query_posts` should never be used. Custom queries created with `WP_Query` and `get_posts` should be reset with `wp_reset_postdata()`. `query_posts` should be reset with `wp_reset_query`

Comment: Thanks Pieter, you have been so helpful!

Comment: That's weird. It must be a mistake. It doesn't let me vote a second time unless you edit your answer. Can you edit your answer by putting a period or something in there? I can upvote afterwards. Sorry about that! --- By the way, Pieter, do you have any tips for images regarding my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598980/images-in-wordpress-efficient-method)

Comment: Hmm when I now click upvote it goes to -1, and clicking upvote a second time it displays 0. Let me know if there is anything else I can do...

Comment: Hahaha, no thanks, I had this feeling that it wasn't you who downvoted me. Was actually strange that you said you've made a mistake. I know exactly who is was who downvoted me. You accepted another answer, and then you unaccepted that answer and excepted mine. That guy removed his answer and out spite downvoted mine, some kind of revenge. Quite childish I would say :-) Enjoy

Comment: Yeah I thought maybe I downvoted by accident since the checkmark button is next to it. 
Next time I will wait to checkmark. Well, hope he's not too mad. Pieter, one quick question about the second block of code in my original question. 
For my pagination in index.php, the code contains: ----- global $wp_query; ----- Is this okay to use? 
And because there is a main loop, I would need to reset pagination with ----- wp_reset_postdata(); ---- correct?

Comment: No, you don't need to reset the main query, that is done internally. Only custom queries needs to be reset. `$wp_query` is the global used by the main query. To make the main querie's objects available **outside** the loop, you need to call the global `$wp_query`, so that is correct in your function

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    get_header(); ?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
            $categories = get_categories(); //get all the categories

            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $category_id= $category->term_id; ?>

                <div><?php echo $category->name ?></div>

                <?php
                    query_posts("category=$category_id&posts_per_page=100");

                    if (have_posts()) {
                        while (have_posts()) {
                            the_post(); ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                            <?php }
                        }
                    }
            } ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```