# query_posts() should be avoided?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am reading that `query_posts()` should be avoided in favor of `wp_query()` and `pre_get_posts()`. I am not confident with messing with the Loop and do not fully understand the codex.

Does the code below use `query_posts()` ? If yes and since `query_posts()` should be avoided, can you suggest a method that does not use `query_posts()` but still accomplish the same thing?

This code in `functions.php` is used to sort posts by random or by price.

```
function my_custom_query($query){
 if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

   $sort= $_GET['sort'];

   if($sort == "pricelow"){
     $query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' );
     $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
     $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }

  if($sort == "random"){
     $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }

 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_query' );
```

.
Link A (Random) and Link B (Price) are posted in my menu by using this code. Thus the visitor to the website can sort the posts simply by clicking a link.

```
<a href="http://website.com/?sort=A">Random</a>
<a href="http://website.com/?sort=B">Price</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done a very detailed explanation on this very topic on WPSE, and for the sake of the value and benefit it might have for SO users, here is the complete post copied from that question on WPSE. For interest sake, here is a link to the complete post on WPSE: [Some doubts about how the main query and the custom query works in this custom theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/155956/31545)

Your actual question is basically when to run a custom query and when to make use of the main query. Lets break it down in three parts

**PART ONE**

When to run a custom query (This is not a definitive list)

- To create custom content sliders
- To create a featured content area in a page
- On page.php templates if you need to display posts
- If you require custom content on a static front page
- Display related, popular or informational posts
- Any other secondary or supplementary content outside the scope of the main query

When to make use of the main query.

To display the primary content on

- On your homepage and the page set as a blogpage in the backend
- All archive pages which includes templates like archive.php, category.php, author.php, taxonomy.php, tag.php and date.php

**PART TWO**

> To select all the featured posts I use this line that create a new WP_Query object that define a query having the specific tag featured:
>
> So, from what I have understand, this is not the WordPres main query but it is a new query created by me. From what I have understand it is better create a new query (as done) and not use the main query when I want perform this kind of operations

Correct. This falls out of scope for the main query. This is secondary or supplementary content which cannot be created with the main query. You **SHOULD ALWAYS** use either [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to create your custom queries.

**NEVER USE** [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to create custom queries, or even any other query. My emphasis.

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Moving on

> Ok, going on I show all the posts that have not the featured tag, to do this I use this code snippet that on the contrary modify the main query:
>
> ```
> query_posts( array( 'tag__not_in' => array ( $term->term_id )));
> ```
>
> So I think that this is pretty horrible. Is it true?

That is all wrong and your statement is unfortunately true. As said before, **NEVER** use `query_posts`. It runs a complete new query, which is bad for performance, and it most cases breaks pagination which is an integral part of the main query for pagination to work correctly.

This is your primary content, so you should be using the main query with the default loop, which should look like this, and this is all you need

```
<?php
    if (have_posts()) :
        // Start the Loop.
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
get_template_part('content', get_post_format());

        endwhile;
    else :
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        get_template_part('content', 'none');

    endif;
?>
```

You can completely get rid of this part, delete it, burn it and forget about it

```
<?
// get the term using the slug and the tag taxonomy
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'featured', 'post_tag' );
// pass the term_id to tag__not_in
query_posts( array( 'tag__not_in' => array ( $term->term_id )));
?>
```

OK, once you've done that, you'll see that posts from the feature tag appear in your home page using the main query and default loop.

The correct way of removing this tag from the homepage is with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). This is the **proper way to alter the main query** and the hook you should **always** use to make changes to your primary content loop.

So, the code with `pre_get_posts` is correct and this is the function that you should use. Just one thing, always do a check that you are not on an admin page because `pre_get_posts` alters the back end as well. So this is the proper code to use in functions.php to remove posts tagged *featured* from the homepage

```
function exclude_featured_tag( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag__not_in', 'array(ID OF THE FEATURED TAG)' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_featured_tag' );
```

**PART THREE**

Extra reading material which will be helpful in future

- [Conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)
- [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/31545)
- [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/31545)
- [Query Overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview)
- [Guidance with The Loop for CMS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/151771/31545)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Pieter. Some questions. You say to 'check that you are not on an admin page' but what is an admin page? ----- If in single.php you have a main loop and a secondary loop (for Related Posts), you would use this code for the second loop: ----- $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ----- correct? Also, do you reset with wp_reset_postdata() for second loops? Do I need to reset both loops or just the second loop?

Comment: An admin page refers to any back end page. You are totally correct on your assumption for related posts, that should be a custom query, and yes, you **need to** reset every custom query, otherwise you will break other queries on the same page. No need to reset the main query, that is build in.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Creating a new WP_Query() object is always fine.</strike>

```
$sort= $_GET['sort'];

   if($sort == "pricelow"){
     $sort_args = array('meta_key' => 'price', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order', 'ASC');
     $new_query = new WP_Query($sort_args);
    }

    blah blah blah...
```

No no no sorry about that. I didn't see the pre_get_posts hook.

The code in your question is good for hooking queries. As in described in [WordPress Plugin API/Action Reference/pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts):

> pre_get_posts runs before WP_Query has been setup.

So it hooks the default WP_Query() where you want (in your code, it changes WP_Query on GET request).

In your template files, use new WP_Query($args).

Comment: Just to be clear...  The code in my question should NOT be used - is it because it uses query_posts() ? You say you didn't see the pre_get_posts hook at first, why did that change things - does it make the code in my question okay to use?

Comment: Yes, your code seems safe and secure because WordPress' documentation says so (check the link in my answer). By the way, you didn't use query_posts() function in your code, you used $query object.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for clearing that up. One question - I would not need to use your code..... $new_query = new WP_Query($sort_args); ..... right?

Comment: Short answer: yes. If you want to hook spesific query in your functions.php, your code is good. In a template file (like home.php, single.php, page.php etc) you must not change WordPress' $query object.