# WP_Query with “post_title LIKE 'something%'” and category

Tags: wordpress

I need to do a WP_Query with a LIKE on the post_title and category

This query_post is not working

```
query_posts(
     array(
        'post_type' => 'add_buying',
        'like' => $keywords,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'taxonomy' => 'add_country',
        'term' => 'drawing'
 ));
```

Comment: Please state _what_ is not working with your query.

Answer (score 8):

Change your second parameter to 's' and I think it's going to work:

```
$args = array(      
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    's'           => $search_term,
    'post_status' => 'publish'    
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And good luck

Comment: adding second parameter with 's' will not only search in titles but also post content . That will not be the most relevant result.

Answer (score 7):

Check [this url](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Search_Parameter) and change the `like` parameter.

```
query_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'add_buying',
's' => $keywords,
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'taxonomy' => 'add_country',
'term' => 'drawing' 
));
```

Comment: Just as a side note, this also searches with in the content of a post.

Comment: I realise that the context of this answer is based on the original question, but as a general note to everyone else: _never, ever use_ `query_posts` (For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/988246). It should only ever be used by the core. Use one of the many, many other functions available like `WP_Query` or `get_posts`, where the same array of arguments can be used safely.

Answer (score 2):

title (string) - use post title (available with Version 4.4).

```
$args = array(      
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'title'       => $title,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```