# Show custom fields with query_posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I used the plugin "[Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/)" for wordpress.

I created a custom post called "slides" and created 2 custom fields "slide" and "phrase".

When I do :

```
$args=array(
            'post_type' => 'slides',            
            'posts_per_page' => 5
    );

$my_query = query_posts($args);

print_r($my_query);
```

I get the posts but I don't get any of the custom fields. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom fields aren't returned as post objects. That is why you don't see them when doing a `var_dump()` of your query. You have to retrieve them manually unfortunately. You have to make use of [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retrieve custom field data for a post

A point of note, never use `query_posts`. You should rather use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

**WHY SHOULD `query_posts` NOT BE USED**

Further info which you should read - [query_posts() should be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/1908141)

Comment: Is there a reason why I shouldnt use query_posts?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an answer I've done recently. There are also linked answers in that answer which you should read. I hope that info will help you in future. Enjoy :-)