# Wordpress: have template output all posts with category x where x is assigned dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a series of pages that display the posts within a single category. To do this I use the following PHP code:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'category' => '$CATEGORY', 'numberposts' => 10000000000);
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

My problem is that the $CATEGORY does not seem to contain the category as a string. I have tried using both %s and $id but as I have not declared that it is the category id I am wanting it fails to work. The resulting output has been either an error or all the posts regardless of category.

What argument will convey the category string?

Below is a page illustrating the problem. This is a category page, meaning it should hold all the necessary info. If it was working it would only show the topmost post as it is the only post en site that has the "Press Release" category. Worth mentioning that I have another page just like it called "Dokument" and it displays the press release.

Page: http://www.skinwellness.se/category/pressrelease/

Comment: You should be using `'cat'`. If you want to use the category name, instead of an ID, you can use `'category_name'`

Comment: I changed it to 'category' => 'cat'
Not working, what'd I miss? :)

Comment: `'category'` is not a thing. You need to use `'cat'` or `'category_name'`

Comment: @rnevius
If I understand you, the code should be something like:
`'$args = array( 'cat' => '$id',`?
Tried this with $id and %s, still not working.

Comment: How is `$CATEGORY` generated

Comment: @PieterGoosen It is not, it is simply something I wrote as a placeholder.

Comment: I don't understand "My problem is that the $CATEGORY does not seem to contain the category as a string"

Comment: I want the $CATEGORY to be replaced with an argument which provides the category of the current page (it is a category page) and as such the information should be there.

Comment: Why don't you use the default loop inside your category.php. Don't use a custom query

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/1908141)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thank you. This has helped me somewhat but I still can't figure out the syntax for doing what he does but with categories. Also he seems to set a static value for what category to show/not show. I want to set a dynamically assigned value, so that the category page for documents shows only the posts categorized as documents wihtout having to create a separete template for this archive.

The page already does this with the header, it becomes the name of the category with `<h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( '%s', 'twentythirteen' )); ?></h1>`

I am a complete beginner! ^^

Comment: I don't use the default loop as I have been unable to edit the way the list of posts is displayed in the category archive without also editing the way a single post is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I did not notice this before, but it seems that you are using the bundled theme twentythirteen. Simply delete the category.php from your child theme. If you have made changes to the parent theme directly, you should get a fresh copy of the theme, and create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) with all your modifications. Never make changes to a theme that you did not write. When such themes update, all you changes will be gone forever

You should then just need the `pre_get_posts` section in your child theme's functions.php to make everyone work

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You problem is purely your custom loop. As explained in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/1908141), you should not be using custom queries in place of the main query on any type of archive page or on your home page

To solve this, revert back to the default loop. This is all you should have. No `get_posts` or foreach loops

```
if( have_posts() ) {
   while( have_posts() ) {
   the_post();

   // Add your loop elements here like the_title() and the_content()

   }
}
```

This should fix the problem that when you visit a category page, only the category been viewed will be viewed, no posts from other categories will be shown

Now, if you need to change anything on your category page, use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to do that. Make use of the [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) conditional tag to target your category pages only. You can also target a specific category with this tag

Say for instance, you need to change the posts per page on you category page, as your case, display all posts with no pagination, you can do this in your functions.php

```
function so26589648_category_ppp( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so26589648_category_ppp' );
```

If you need to for example change the order to `ASC` and need to order posts by author, you can do this

```
function so26589648_category_ppp( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'author' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so26589648_category_ppp' );
```

You should see [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for all available parameters to use

Comment: I have now changed so that my theme is a child theme. Looking into the rest of your advice right now.

Comment: No problem, let me know about your progress

Comment: I don't get it. I am supposed to use the original category.php and then insert `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so26589648_category_ppp' );` into my functions.php? That doesn't do anything.

Sorry for having a head made from rocks ;)

Comment: O crap, sorry, There is a syntax error in my code. Will update now. `!is_admin` should be `!is_admin()` I wrote this code in a hurry this morning before I left for work. Test it, it should work now. Remember, this goes into you functions.php in your child theme

Comment: Thank you, it now correctly displays only the posts from the select category. Where do I tweak the layout of these entries? I want to only display the header with the date just below that. I also need to be able to edit the font and general css of these lines.

Comment: This is quite another question on its own which I will explain. You should ask this as a new question as it is out of scope of this one :-). Please accept this answer and move on to your new question