# Order or orderby not working in WP_Query when you are in category page

Tags: wordpress

I have the next WP_Query in footer.php in my wordpress:

```
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $argsLast = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'category__not_in' => array(193,189,192,195,207,190,213),
                                );

$ultimosposts = new WP_Query( $argsLast );
```

And it works fine in all pages of my wordpress except the category pages.

I have done several tests and the paremeter  which doesn't work are 'order' or 'orderby'.

I would be grateful if someone could explain what is going on.

SOLVED: The problem was caused by a plugin: Sort Categories By Title

I deactivated the plugin and I'm sorting the posts in category using the next code in functions.php of my theme (a lot of thanks to @PieterGoosen, now I understand much better the queries in Wordpress):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'orden_posts_categoria');

function orden_posts_categoria($q){
     if (!is_admin() 
          && $q->is_main_query() 
          && $q->is_category() 
    ) {
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
```

**Note: this code is from @PieterGoosen**

In this way, I modify the main query of wordpress. So it is very important setting the correct conditions in the selective structure.

Comment: 'category__not_in'... shouldn't it be 'category_not_in' ?

Comment: Nope all not_in's have __ prefixed.

Comment: Check for any custom filter like `pre_get_posts()` that specifically targets category pages

Comment: I searched about any custom filter and I didn't find any in the theme code but there was a plugin which was modifying  the query:
"Sort Categories By Title"

I deactivated it and the problem was solved.

Is there a way to keep the plugin and make my WP Query working?. Reset the filters before my query or something like that?

Comment: I really do suspect that the plugin you are using is a pile of crap. It should not be changing queries that are on the same page. What does the plugin exactly do. Does it sort posts on the category page by title and not date. If so, we can correct the problem without having to use that plugin. Just a tip, if you need to direct a comment to me specifically, use @PieterGoosen in your comment. Without that, I don't get pinged if you post a comment

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have deactivated the plugin and sort the posts by title using code in the category page. 

I have changed the usual while(have_posts()) using the code which I put in the main post.

I'm not an expert of wordpress query loop . Do you know if this code has a good performance?

Comment: It would be nice if you can accept my answer as it solved your issue. Just one tip, if my code did not work as is and yours did, then you are using a very outdated version of PHP. Mine need PHP 5.3, so you are using versions older than that which is a huge security risk for your site

Comment: You are a harsh man that doesn't take others into consideration. The answer from @PieterGoosen works for me, and it worked for you as well as it is evidently clear from your edit as you have used his code. Not accepting his answer or not even upvoting it to give him at least some kind of credit is really all in bad taste.

Comment: @user4717687 thanks for your concerns, appreciated. All I can say is, if it makes the OP happy to be this way, let it be. We cannot unfortunately do anything about it. Enjoy :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Sorry, I didn't understand the last comments. Maybe because I'm new in stackoverflow.
How could I accept your answer? I tried to vote your answer but I couldn't (Vote up requires 15 reputation).
I thank you for your code in my main post.I really appreciate your help,  what is the problem here?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you have deactivated the plugin as in my opinion, the plugin is a pile off crap due to the fact that it breaks page functionalities. I can only speculate, but it either uses `pre_get_posts` wrongly or it uses `query_posts` which you should **never ever** use.

To solve your issue, you need to go back to the dafault loop which should look like this

```
if ( have_posts() ) { // Sometimes category pages don't have this, not really necessary
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Your markup and template tags

    }
}
```

You again should see posts on your category page ordered by date as per default.

Now, to solve the issue of sorting your posts by title on category pages, we will use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query variables before the main query run. This is the recommended method, you should never replace the main query with a custom one to solve these kind of issues. It leads to other issues, specially wrong posts and wrong pagination

In your functions.php or your own custom plugin, add the following

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ($q )
{
    if (        !is_admin() // Check that we are on the front end and not back end
          && $q->is_main_query() // Make sure we only alter the main query
          && $q->is_category() // Only target category pages
    ) {
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
});
```

The check I have done is very very important. `pre_get_posts` alters all instances of `WP_Query`, not only the main query, and this happens back end and front end and on **all** pages. Always make sure that you use these checks when using `pre_get_posts`

You should now have your category pages sorted by post title, and your custom query 8n the footer should also now correctly on category pages.

Just one last tip, to avoid custom filters altering your custom `WP_Query` instances, use `'suppress_filters' => true` in your query arguments. `get_posts` does the same to avoid custom filters altering the output

### EDIT

Just on the issue of queries, you should take your time and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/1908141) I have done on the subject of the main query and custom queries

Comment: Please recheck my code, I had a syntax error. Sorry about that