# Displaying Tags on taxonomy page

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I currently have the option in my CMS, to add tags to my custom post type single page.

Now, I am wanting to display this tag as a 'featured' item.
So, In my taxonomy-'filename', I use the following code which gathers the tags and displays them in the taxonomy page:

```
            <?php 
        $args = array(
          'tag_slug__and' => array('sector1'),
          'post_type' => array( 'sectors' )
          );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
         <?php echo "<div class='col-md-6' style='margin-bottom:20px;'>"; ?>
         <div class="row mobilemargin">
          <div class="categorytiletextsector1">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopr"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'categoryimage', array('class' => 'sector1img hovereffect')); ?> </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="testdiv">
               <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
               <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <?php echo "</div>"; ?>

     </a>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Now, my issue is, this will display the selected tag on every category page now, as it is set on the taxonomy page.

How can I make this only set on the current category.

So If my item is in the 'category A', only the category page of 'A' would show this, using the items category?

Any help would be great

Edit. 
Used this code, hoping this should work, but no luck

```
$args = array(
    'tag_slug__and' => array( 'sector1' ),
    'post_type'     => array( 'sectors' ),
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
            'terms'    => get_queried_object_id(),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your custom query. One very important note here is, never ever change replace the main query with a custom one on any type of archive page or the home page. I have explained everything in detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/1908141) recently. Make sure to read it and all the linked posts as this will benefit you a lot

Your solution would be to remove your custom query and replace this with the default loop that we all know

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        // Your template tags and html mark up

    }
}
```

If you need to change anything in the main query, use `pre_get_posts` to do so

### EDIT

Your best idea here would be to use a full `tax_query` to display posts that is in the selected taxonomy term and tag

You can try something like this: (*Requires at least PHP 5.4+. Also, this untested*)

```
$q = get_queried_object();
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'sectors',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => $q->taxonomy,
            'terms' => $q->term_id,
            'include_children' => false // Exclude child terms
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'sector1', //I believe this is the slug
        ],
    ],
];
```

For older PHP versions, use the following

```
$q = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sectors',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $q->taxonomy,
            'terms' => $q->term_id,
            'include_children' => false // Exclude child terms
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'sector1', //I believe this is the slug
        ),
    ),
);
```

### EDIT 2

To exclude posts that are in the `sector1` tag and any other `sectorX` tag, you can do the following

You can try something like this: (*Requires at least PHP 5.4+. Also, this untested*)

```
$q = get_queried_object();
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'sectors',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => $q->taxonomy,
            'terms' => $q->term_id,
            'include_children' => false // Exclude child terms
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'sector1', //I believe this is the slug
            'operator' => 'NOT_IN'
        ],
    ],
];
```

For older PHP versions, use the following

```
$q = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sectors',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $q->taxonomy,
            'terms' => $q->term_id,
            'include_children' => false // Exclude child terms
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'sector1', //I believe this is the slug
            'operator' => 'NOT_IN'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Just note, you can pass an array of tags to the `terms` parameter like this

```
'terms' => array( 'sector1', 'sector2', 'etc' ),
```

or short array syntax

```
'terms' => ['sector1', 'sector2', 'etc'],
```

### EDIT 3

As this is your main query, you need to make a few changes. As I have said, remove the custom query. Your main loop should look something like this

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?> 
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> 
        <?php echo "<div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12' style='margin-bottom:30px;'>"; ?> 
        <div class="row mobilemargin"> 
            <div class="categorytiletext2"> 
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 nopr"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'categoryimage', array('class' => 'hovereffect newimgheight')); ?> </div> 
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mobilewhite"> 
                    <div class="testdiv"> 
                        <h5 class="captext"><?php the_title(); ?></h5> 
                        <?php $trimexcerpt = get_the_excerpt(); 

                        $shortexcerpt = wp_trim_words( $trimexcerpt, $num_words = 10, $more = '… ' ); 

                        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><p>' . $shortexcerpt . '</p></a>'; 

                        ?> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
        <?php echo "</div>"; ?> 

        </a> 
        <!-- If there is no posts, display an error message --> 
    <?php endwhile; 
else: ?> 
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p> 
<?php endif; ?> 
<!-- If there is no posts, display an error message -->
```

You can now use `pre_get_posts` to remove the desired tag from your taxonomy pages. In your functions.php, do the following: (*Requires PHP 5.3+, and is also untested*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_tax() ) {
       $q->set( 'tag__not_in', array( 145 ) );
    }
});
```

For older versions use

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so30256167_remove_tags' );
function so30256167_remove_tags( $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_tax() ) {
       $q->set( 'tag__not_in', array( 145 ) );
    }
}
```

Just remember to change `145` to your exact tag **id** or an array of tag**ids**

### EDIT 4

If you don't have the tag ids, you can use `get_term_by()` to get the tag id from the tag slug. Something like this will do: (*Requires PHP 5.3+, and is also untested*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_tax() ) {
        $tag_object = get_term_by( 'slug', 'sector1', 'post_tag' ); 
        $tagID = $tag_object->term_id; 

       $q->set( 'tag__not_in', array( $tagID ) );
    }
});
```

For older versions use

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so30256167_remove_tags' );
function so30256167_remove_tags( $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_tax() ) {
        $tag_object = get_term_by( 'slug', 'sector1', 'post_tag' ); 
        $tagID = $tag_object->term_id; 

       $q->set( 'tag__not_in', array( $tagID ) );
    }
}
```

If you have an array of tag slugs, you can replace the following

```
$tag_object = get_term_by( 'slug', 'sector1', 'post_tag' ); 
$tagID = $tag_object->term_id; 

$q->set( 'tag__not_in', array( $tagID ) );/*
```

with

```
$tag_array = array( 'slug1', 'slug2', 'slug3' );
foreach ( $tag_array as $tag ) {
    $tag_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $tag, 'post_tag' ); 
    $tagids[] = $tag_object->term_id;
} 
$q->set( 'tag__not_in', $tagids );
```

Just remember to change the slugs accordingly

### EDIT 5

Your final code in functions.php with `pre_get_posts` should be

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so30256167_remove_tags' );
function so30256167_remove_tags( $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_tax() ) {
        $tag_array = array( 'sector1', 'sector2', 'sector3', 'sector4' );
        foreach ( $tag_array as $tag ) {
            $tag_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $tag, 'post_tag' ); 
            $tagids[] = $tag_object->term_id;
        } 
        $q->set( 'tag__not_in', $tagids );    
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood your question

Comment: The Loop is working, It is getting the posts which are tagged, but it will display it on EVERY category. I just need a way to make it only display on the category it relates too, which i thought I had done with the 'terms'    => get_queried_object_id(),

Comment: Ok, I don't understand your question, is this your main loop.

Comment: This is just a loop, which gets any tagged post with the name 'sector1'. 

This loop works fine, it gets the tagged post and displays it. But It displays it in every category, I need it to only display in the ctegory it belongs to

Comment: Your terminology is confusing me, what exactly is `sector1`. How did you create this. Do you know the difference between categories, taxonomies and terms. What is it what you are trying to do. What happens when you replace all your code (custom loop) with the loop in my answer

Comment: Sector 1 is the tag which can be added on my custom post type 'sectors'.  

So, in the custom post type of 'sectors', you can have a sector, which can then have a tag added to it

Comment: Where does categories come in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78025/discussion-between-jonathan-and-pieter-goosen).