# Pagination : Page 3 Not Found in a WordPress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

My problem is pagination which I am using in Wordpress. I used the plugin *WP Pagenavi*. I'm not really sure what is wrong with it.

I found the answer to my problem using this code :

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=15'.'&paged=' . $paged); ?>
```

But to my disappointment, when I reduced the posts_per_page to 5, I CAN get the pagination to work until page 2 but when I click page 3 and so on, WordPress can't find it. I used another solution from my research:

```
<?php
$limit = '5';
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('cat=4&showposts=' . $limit . '&paged=' . $paged);
$wp_query->is_archive = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
?>
```

It still didn't help. I don't want to touch *functions.php*. I'm only editing *category.php*.

Check my block of code below :

```
    <?php if (is_category('category1')) { ?>

<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=1&posts_per_page=15'.'&paged=' . $paged); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- SOME CODE TO POST THE POST -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php } else if (is_category('category2')) { ?>

<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=2&posts_per_page=15'.'&paged=' . $paged); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- SOME CODE TO POST THE POST -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php } else if (is_category('category3')) { ?>

<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=5'.'&paged=' . $paged); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- SOME CODE TO POST THE POST -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php } else if (is_category('category4')) { ?>

<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=5'.'&paged=' . $paged); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- SOME CODE TO POST THE POST -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi() ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php } else { ?>

<!-- SOME CODE -->

<?php } ?>
```

Please note that category1 and category2 display 5 posts while the other 2 categories will display 15 posts. And these are all in the category.php.I don't want to use the # of posts set in the Settings > Reading.

If you think the *if statement* and putting also the *cat ID* is redundant, well, it does not get posts of that category name.

**UPDATE**

I used this code:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php $args = array ('post_type' => 'post','cat' => '4','posts_per_page' => '5','paged' => $paged);?>
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query ($args);?>
```

Again, it worked BUT it only shows two pages! I don't even know where the 3rd page is, supposedly there should be a 3rd page.

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks pagination and the main query. As this is your category.php, you also do not need a custom query, use the default loop, and then use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query accordingly

Comment: I tried using pre_get_posts but no posts are showing. I don't know why. Sorry, I'm not good with PHP so the explanation is quite hard to understand.

Comment: No problem, great to hear you have tried `pre_get_posts`. I think it is just a misunderstanding somewhere which made you fail. I will try to post a solution. I'm posting from my phone, so it is difficult to code. Also, I cannot test what I code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some serious issues

- Never ever use `query_posts`, ever. It breaks the main query object on which so many plugins and functionalities rely, it also breaks pagination and fails silently, so it is really hard to debug pagination when it does fail. If you really really have to use a custom query, use `WP_Query` instead. You should take your time to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/1908141) and all of the linked posts. It is really helpful as it tells you why you should not use `query_posts` and when should you use custom queries and when not
- This point are coupled to the first one and the linked post. You must never change the main query to use a custom one on the homepage or any type of archive page. This always causes much more issues than what is actually solves. Always use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query before it runs. This way, you lets the main query handle all the heavy lifting correctly without you breaking a sweat.

Now, to fix your issue:

- First of all, remove all your queries, and just add this code in your category.php (*Remember to replace your pagination function, `wp_pagenavi()`*)

  ```
  if ( have_posts() ) {
      while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();

          // Your loop with template tags and html mark up

      }
      wp_pagenavi();
  }
  ```

  You will immediately see that your category posts are showing correctly, but the amount of posts will be the same as what you set in the back end under reading
- We will now use `pre_get_posts` to alter the amount of posts per category. For this, add the following code to your functions.php (*Requires PHP 5.3+ and the code is untested*)

  ```
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
  {
      if (        !is_admin() // Very important, otherwise back end queries will be affected as well
            && $q->is_main_query() // Very important, we just need to modify the main query
            && $q->is_category() // Only target category pages
      ) {
          // Check on which category page we are and set posts_per_page accordingly
          if ( $q->is_category( array( 1, 2 ) ) )
              $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );

          if ( $q->is_category( array( 3, 4 ) ) )
              $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
      }
  });
  ```

This should basically do it.

Comment: Another question, in my admin page, the posts are also displaying in the same number set in the function.

Comment: That is your category ids, so `$q->is_category( array( 1, 2 ) )` should check if you are on category page 1 or 2

Comment: Check my update code, forgot `()` for `!is_admin` check

Comment: This is frustrating. It was working a while ago and now it's not anymore. T.T
There are no posts showing with the code you gave me.

Comment: Did you add your loop elements like `the_content()`

Comment: Hi! I coded it like this `if($query->is_category('6') || $query->is_category('3'))` then set it to post 5 posts but there is no 2nd page. It only shows you 1st page.

Comment: Are you sure you have more that 5 posts. Add `echo $wp_query->found_posts` anywhere in your template, it will show you how many posts there is matching the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78394/discussion-between-monica-negapatan-and-pieter-goosen).

Comment: I'll try, my phone stuffs around in chat

Answer (score 0):

We have finally arrived to a final answer and working code!

If you read Mr. Pieter Goosen's answer above, it will help you. It really helped me. So, I'm going to give you the final answers. This is actually custom number of post in every category disregarding what is set in the settings.

So in my category.php

```
    <?php if (is_category('category1')) { ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Your loop with template tags and html mark up

    }
    wp_pagenavi();
}
?>

<?php } else if (is_category('category2')) { ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Your loop with template tags and html mark up

    }
    wp_pagenavi();
}
?>

<?php } else if (is_category('category3')) { ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Your loop with template tags and html mark up

    }
    wp_pagenavi();
}
?>

<?php } else if (is_category('category4')) { ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Your loop with template tags and html mark up

    }
    wp_pagenavi();
}
?>

<?php } ?>
```

**WHERE** *category1 and category2* will display **5 posts**, *category3* and *category4* will display **15 posts**.
This is what you're going to place in your functions.php.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function($q) {
    if (!is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_category()) {
        if ($q->is_category( array(1,2) )) {
            $q->set('posts_per_page', 5);
        }
        if ($q->is_category( array(3,4) )) {
            $q->set('posts_per_page', 15);
        }
    }
    return;
});
```

**WHERE** the numbers inside the array are category IDs.
If you compare my code and Sir Pieter's, it's almost the same BUT I added a `return;` before the `add_action()` is closed. But I'm quoting what Sir Pieter said:

> It is really strange that you should return. pre_get_posts is a
>   action, not a filter. But any way, glad it is solved

If it still doesn't work for you, my permalink is set to:

http://www.example.com/sample-post/[/%postname%/].

I also have a *WP No Category Base* plugin to eliminate */category/* in my category URL. So instead of *www.example.com/category/category1*, it will be ***www.example.com/category1***.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this could help for those who, like me, use a **DIVI CHILD THEME** !

I finally found the solution by searching **divi pagination**.

In fact, in my case, I built a divi child theme. However, the post per page in my custom category page is set to 3, but into my **divi > theme option the Number of Posts displayed on Category page were set to 6**.

That why the page 3 was displaying an error 404. So, I set it to 1.

I read on a post that the "**Blog pages show at most**" into the **settings > reading option** have to be under the post_per_page custom query (for the home page), or else, it create a 404 page.

However, it look like that the Number of Posts displayed into the Divi option, **overwrite the Blog pages show at most**. Here why into my category.php page, I was stuck on page 3.

I leave you my tiny code about my custom category.php page for divi theme child :

```
<?php 
//query{
    //print_r(get_queried_object());
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $the_cat_nicename = $category->slug;
    $the_cat_name = $category->name;

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args_s = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => $the_cat_nicename,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby'=>'date',
    'order'=>'DESC'));
//query}
if ( $args_s->have_posts())
{
    echo $the_cat_name;
    echo '<br/>';
    while ( $args_s->have_posts())
    {
        $args_s->the_post();
        $the_id=get_the_ID($post->ID);
        echo $the_id.'<br/>';
    }
    if ($args_s->max_num_pages > 1) 
    {
        echo get_next_posts_link( $GLOBALS['older_post_lang'], $args_s->max_num_pages );
        echo get_previous_posts_link( $GLOBALS['newer_post_lang'] );
    }
}
//wordpress _have_posts}
?>
```

Do not forget to set your Number of Posts displayed on Category page to 1 into your **Divi > theme option**.