# How to display latest products, but excluding a specific category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Guys with that I get the latest products added:

```
[recent_products]
```

With that I can in a certain category:

```
[product_category category = "book"]
```

QUESTION:

How do I get the product "recent_products" excluding a certain category, the one above for example.

I tried it and not getting results:

```
[recent_products per_page="10" category="book" operator="NOT IN"]
```

Comment: You are using shortcodes, possibly from a plugin. Unless the plugin offers the desired behaviour, you cannot get the results you need.

Comment: By "not getting results" do you mean that book products are still showing up? `operator` does appear to be a parameter as seen [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php#L298)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `query_posts`. And also refer this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).
`query_posts( 'cat=-3' );` This will category id 3

Comment: The first sentence of the codex article is "Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes."

Comment: yes we can use this function. And it won't create any problem. I suggest this function because it's the simplest way to exclude category. What is first line it doesn't matter

Comment: Won't create any problem? It will completely stomp on/override the main `$query` object, which can be a major problem. The first line in the codex is very important because it is advising that `query_posts()` is not the best way to make a secondary query. Using `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` is the accepted "best practice" for querying posts (and can exclude a category) and has been for several years.

Comment: yes i understand what you are saying but we can use `wp_reset_postdata();` at the end of `while` loop.

Comment: Obviously you can do what you want, but it is important to inform new users that this is the wrong approach. It's been covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/383847) and [here] and you can find plenty of articles via Google about how you shouldn't use it anymore. Even core WP devs such as Andrew Nacin say [don't use `query_posts`](http://wordpress.tv/2013/03/15/andrew-nacin-wp_query-wordpress-in-depth/) you don't use `query_posts`.