# How can I use query_posts to filter posts from a specific year?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I use the query_posts functions within Wordpress to filter my posts out by a specific year?

Here's my current code:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=10');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="testpost">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <hr class="smallblue">
        <h5><?php the_time(); ?></h5>
        <h6><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h6>
    </div>
</a>
<?php 
   endwhile; endif; >
   wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: Please never, *ever* use `query_posts` (Reference: stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/988246). It should only ever be used by the core. Use one of the many other functions available like `WP_Query` or `get_posts`, where the same array of arguments can be used safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=3&posts_per_page=10&year=2004'); ?>
```

pass the year to the query

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`date_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) argument of `WP_Query`, which has the advantage of being slightly more readable:

```
$args = array(
    'cat'               => 3,
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => 2017,
        ),
    ),
);

$myQuery = new WP_Query($args);

// Or $myQuery = get_posts($args);

if ($myQuery->have_posts()) : 
    
    while ($myQuery->have_posts()) : $myQuery->the_post();
        
        //  Output
        
    endwhile;
endif;
```

But please: [never, *ever* use `query_posts`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25589475/988246). It should only ever be used by the core. Use one of the many, many other functions available like `WP_Query` or `get_posts`, where the same array of arguments can be used safely.

Comment: Thank you I'll research this further. Appreciated.

Comment: is there a point to call `if have_posts()` as well as `while have_posts()`? from my understanding, `while` won't run anyway if the condition isn't met so the `if` is redundant

Comment: @gilad905 Using `if (have_posts())` is a very standard way of doing things - look in the source of practically any theme. And I would much rather always double-check if a thing exists before looping through it.