# Pagination not working in WP_Query()

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

My pagination is not working with `WP_Query()`.

I have a total of three posts. Page 1 correctly displays all three posts. But page 2 displays the same three posts. In fact, there should not be a page 2 since page 1 displays all three posts already.

What could be wrong?

.
Loop in `index.php`

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=1');
if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>

<?php my_pagination(); ?>
```

.
.
Pagination in `functions.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
    function my_pagination() {
        global $wp_query;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer   
        echo paginate_links( array(
             'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ), 
             'format' => '?paged=%#%',
             'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), 
             'prev_next'    => True,
             'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ) );
}
```

Comment: See my answer to your other post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25589440/1908141). This should fix all your problems

Answer (score 0):

Your query variable in your main loop is `$query` whereas your query variable in your pagination is `$wp_query`. Try using `$query` in place of `$wp_query`.

So for example:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pagination' ) ) :
    function my_pagination() {
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer   
        echo paginate_links( array(
             'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ), 
             'format' => '?paged=%#%',
             'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), 
             'prev_next'    => True,
             'total' => $query->max_num_pages
        ) );
}
```

**Note:** your code seems to be missing an `endif;`

Comment: It didn't work. Pagination completely disappears. I also added more posts to see if page 2 will work, but there is no pagination to go to the next page. What else could be wrong? Is the problem with my main loop? It is used to display posts from a specific category. The pagination was working with a plain loop. Is there another way to call posts from a specific category?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code for your query:

```
global $wp_query;
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query('cat=1&paged=' . $paged);
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
my_pagination();
```

In case it still does not work (that might happen depending on the context), try replacing:

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

with

```
$paged = get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```